# Rails global content_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, helper, content-for

Example:

I have 2 partial _map.haml and _bigmap.haml.

:: _map.haml

```
- content_for :map do
  %script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"}
  ...
```

:: _bigmap.haml

```
- content_for :bigmap do
  %script{:type => "text/javascript", :src => "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"}
  ...
```

In my layout I include javascripts into

```
= yield(:map)
= yield(:bigmap)
```

QUESTION 1:
This means google library will be included twice. How can I handle this so the library is always loaded only once? A was thinking of view heler maybe?

QUESTION 2:
Is it possible to have a global content_for field where each partial appends it's content to it?
Thx.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `inject_js` method into your application helper for use in views:

```
def inject_js
  @javascripts.uniq.collect{ |js|
    javascript_include_tag js
  }.join("\n")
end
```

Then in your application view:

```
%html
  %head
  ...
  = inject_js
```

and in any view that uses bigmap:

```
- @javascripts << 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'
- @javascripts << 'bigmap'
```

or regular map:

```
- @javascripts << 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true'
- @javascripts << 'bigmap'
```

Because `inject_js` uses `@javascripts.uniq`, the Google library will only be loaded once.

`inject_js` code taken from [tog's tog_core](http://github.com/tog/tog_core/blob/d2a7110a365ef121df25957b3018eea66fad98ac/app/helpers/core_helper.rb). There are other methods there as well (inject_css, etc).